# ¿Hay algún atajo de teclado para escribir cualquier letra volada?

Tags: abreviaturas

Hola: Quisiera saber si hay algún atajo de teclado que convierta cualquier letra en volada.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir con "volada"? Algún ejemplo gráfico? ¿Cuál procesador de texto está usando?¿Es en Windows o en Macintosh?

Comment: @alvalongo las letras voladas son las que se usan en números ordenales y en abreviaturas: 1.º, 2.ª, M.ª, etc.

Comment: Esta pregunta no es sobre el idioma español sino sobre interfaces de teclado.

Comment: Podrías usar un Clipboard Manager como por ejemplo Arsclip.